# persistant members in grpc c# service

Tags: c#, grpc

isnt there a way, or am i doing something wrong, to have persistant members in a c# grpc service?

Heres what i mean:

my Service:

```
public class AcquisitionService : Acquisition.AcquisitionBase {
    private string _test;


public override Task<Reply> Test1(Request request, ServerCallContext context) {
    _test = "5";
    _logger.LogInformation("test: " + _test);
    return Task.FromResult(new Reply());
}

public override Task<Reply> Test2(Request request, ServerCallContext context) {
    _logger.LogInformation("test: " + _test);
    return Task.FromResult(new Reply());
}
}
```

when i call these methods like:

```
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7110");
var acqClient = new Acquisition.AcquisitionClient(channel);

acqClient.Test1(new Request {});
acqClient.Test2(new Request {});
```

from service my output in logger is:

```
test: 5
test:
```

why is the content of _test disposed?

Im new to grpc.

Thanks

i tried to add properties but it did not helped.

Comment: in your test2 method should not it be _test1 ? _logger.LogInformation("test: " + Test);

Comment: Share code or just more information on how you arrived at the conclusion that gRPC is causing the issue you've described  (At the application level, gRPC streamlines messaging between clients and back-end services. ),  At the application level, gRPC streamlines messaging between clients and back-end services.

Answer (score 3):

A new instance of `AcquisitionService`  is instantiated for each call.
This means that every instance field is "brand new" for each new call.

You should use a persistence layer like a database or file or something like that to persist the value of your data across calls.

Another way is to make the `_test` field static, then the value will be shared for each instance. Make sure you understand the implications of a shared static field (concurrency and so on).

Comment: so you mean if i create a client instance even between calling procedures with the same client instance there will be a new instance? thats not the behavior i expected..

Comment: when i make the field static it works thank you. but this is against my understanding. Serializing the content isnt possible because in reality im using non serializable types from a foreign api.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to make the service a singleton in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AcquisitionService>();
```

its mentioned here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#service-lifetimes